# upload to s3 from ec2 without access key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can you connect to S3 via s3cmd or mount S3 to and ec2 instance with IAM users and not using access keys?

All the tutorials I see say to use access keys but what if you can't create your own access keys (IT policy).

Comment: A quick search for "s3cmd iam role" would have shown you that you can use IAM roles with s3cmd. Also, you can use the aws cli tool to access S3 via IAM roles.

Comment: *"with IAM users and not using access keys"* doesn't entirely make sense... IAM users are identified by... their access keys.  If "IT policy" is that you can't have access keys, then the question for IT is whether you are authorized to access S3 and how that should be done.  (One assumes the answer would be one of: "use the instance's IAM Role" or "use the following key and secret" or "we already said you can't do that.")

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to access data in Amazon S3: Via an API, or via URLs.

**Via an API**

When accessing Amazon S3 via API (which includes code using an AWS SDK and also the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)), user credentials must be provided in the form of an Access Key and a Secret Key.

The `aws` and `s3cmd` utilities, and also software that mounts Amazon S3 as a drive, require access to the API and therefore require credentials.

If you have been given a login to an AWS account, you should be able to ask your administrators to also create credentials that are associated with your User. These credentials will have exactly the same permissions as your normal login (via Username/password), so it's strange that they would be disallowing it. They can be very useful for automating AWS activities, such as starting/stopping Amazon EC2 instances.

**Via URLs**

Objects stored in Amazon S3 can also be made available via a URL that points directly to the data, eg `s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/object.txt`

To provide public access to these objects without requiring credentials, either add permission to each object or create a [Bucket Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html) that grants access to content within the bucket.

This access method can be used to retrieve individual objects, but is not sufficient to mount Amazon S3 as a drive.